# Obtaining valid binary from blob

Tags: javascript, binary, blob, filereader

I need to get correct binary string (for further operations) from file input. I'm obtaining code via FileReader, but code is wrong. In the next code I'm getting binary string and trying to build blob from it:

```
function sendBlobToBrowser( blob )
{
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'audio.ogg';
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 100)
}

function buildBlobFromString( binaryString )
{
    return new Blob( [ binaryString ], { type : 'audio/ogg' } );
}

$( '#fileInput' ).change( function()
{
    var file = this.files[ 0 ]

    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var binary = this.result;

        console.log( 'Converted string src: ' + binary )

        // trying to build blob
        var builtBlob = buildBlobFromString( binary );
        sendBlobToBrowser( builtBlob )
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString( file );
})
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/093ys9fp/) is the example.
For tests I'm using [this ogg file](https://www.sendspace.com/file/rpt9xx), but it's not about audio web api, it's just some example-file.

I have tired to fight with it :( Really thx.

Comment: better to create something like fiddle, I think plnkr will be best for this case,

Comment: I mean, create working example

Answer (score 0):

1. `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated don't use it
2. The string you get from `readAsBinaryString` is not "binary" its just text the binary part is in how the string is created(each byte is read into a character). Use `readAsArrrayBuffer` if you want the result to be binary.
3. You can use a File to create an Object Url (file instanceof blob === true)

```
function sendBlobToBrowser( blob )
{
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'audio.ogg';
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 100);
}

$( '#fileInput' ).change( function()
{
    var file = this.files[ 0 ];
    sendBlobToBrowser( file );    
});
```

Comment: I don't need to save this file. It's just way of test binary. Key phrase: *I need **to get correct binary string (for further operations)***. I have update link in first post, pls see it.

Comment: Strings in JavaScript are a sequence of 16 bit values, you cannot store arbitrary binary data in them.

Comment: Just replace 8 to 16 in function and u will see what happened :) Happened: Obtained binary: 杏卧Ȁs導찥恜ጁ灏獵效摡āༀ伀杧S猀฀Ŝꀀ⺲ĩ优異味条ࡳ刀捥牯敤r伀杧S猀฀ɜᴀ㝚Í

Comment: Some Jap message instead of binary :(

Comment: I don't know what that means. what do you **actually** want to do with the string?

Comment: Encrypt via pgp. So, for this I need to get correct binary

Comment: And the library you're using only supports strings?

Comment: Can't find another way. It's openpgpjs

Comment: https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs#user-content-encrypt-and-decrypt-uint8array-data-with-pgp-keys

Comment: you can get text or even using xhr request/fetch from objectURL :)

Comment: Only variant - using Uint8Array. Any attempts to get string leads to wrong binary data.